# Stitch Multiple Sequentially Taken Images

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a set of images of a pipe taken by a camera that rotates `360` degrees and captures image every `x` degrees, hence inducing a constant overlap between the images. I need to stitch these images together such that they can be analysed as one big image, perhaps a panoramic image or orthomosaic. Here's a couple of examples:

[image][image]

Because it's a pipe, there's a slight curve in each image, so I am thinking first we can "unroll" the image, and do it for every image. After that, perhaps all those images can be stitched together.

I have tried unwrapping using "six-point" method ( you define cross-section of the cylinder with 3 points from the top and 3 from the bottom) , like you are unwrapping a sticker on a bottle, which is not terrible (can be improved of course). Here's how "unwrapping" looks like:

[image]

Second, `SIFT` is not working well for stitching. I am thinking it's because images are quite similar in nature. But, I am not sure how to best stitch them. This is where I need help. I need to align the crests of the pipe and stitch the images seamlessly - images could be up to 90 or 120. Would love any help here. Thanks.

This is something from a software, which is quite bad:

[image]

Comment: How many images have you stitched together in the last image above?

Comment: camera perspective is very important to figure out this problem. your idea is good but camera capture angle is not always vertical or same for all. Even target will be in a different perspective. You may detect the brighter horizontal lines and try to merge them by one by. But I can say this is a difficult task to handle

Comment: In the above stitched image, two images are used.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk we will make sure that these images are taken in an automated fashion so we hope that variation would be minimal. For now, we can crop above given images and perfect the methodology on them.

Comment: What angle around the pipe's center do these two images cover? I suppose each is 180 degrees. The lesser the angle the easier it is for the "unrolling" algorithm to produce a flatter image. Right now, the images are not flat enough at the seam. You could try taking 4 or if possible 8 images while sweeping around the pipe, while maintaining as same distance as possible from the pipe. Also, increase the contrast in the image, that will help with better feature matching. There are small marks here and there on the pipe that will appear better with contrast enhancement.

Comment: here's what you need: (1) calibrate camera to obtain distortion coefficients. you need non-distorted pictures (2) you need a cylinder model for the pipe, and locate that in every picture. that'll involve locating the threads. (3) then you project the picture onto the cylinder model to obtain a "texture" of the cylinder wall. that is now a nice image you can feed to a stitching pipeline.

Comment: better yet, chuck all that, and make the camera move around the threads/pipe mechanically. then you can work with thin axial slices of picture and can probably ditch all unwarping efforts. -- your task is **optical inspection** that allows **measurements**. that requires fidelity, precision. just throwing a random stitching pipeline at it WILL CAUSE ARTEFACTS and lying pictures.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz you are right. Our task is indeed inspection to start with and will be followed by measurements etc. And, we'll do what you are thinking i.e. we'll mechanically take pictures every `x` degrees. For example, we can take 90 images if we take an image every 4 degrees. Please can you explain further idea of axial slices of picture?

Comment: if you're puzzled by "axial", ignore the word. you're probably already meaning to do exactly that. effectively, you're aiming to do stitching **without feature matching**, just by knowing how much the cam has rotated, and how much that should be in pixels (given some geometry and measurements). -- imagine a flatbed scanner. it's not taking one 2D picture, it's taking lots of 1D "pictures" side by side. what you'll do is something in between.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz this is quite to the point. Thank you so much. Please can you point me towards some implementations using opencv that do stitching without feature matching? I will run a quick test and see how it behaves.

Comment: I don't know any, off-hand. in your place, I'd hack something up based on either plain numpy slicing, or an affine warp (lets you do interpolation) that does nothing but scaling and translation. in the first iteration, I wouldn't even bother with blending between slices/images, or perspective (but later). yes, python will be totally fine, especially for a prototype. all the heavy lifting happens in libraries.

Comment: if/when you have a video of such data, do post it. -- with non-uniform motion, you could do something like https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-determine-average-x-y-motion-of-keypoints-in-video/8983/1 which is somewhat like stitching, but uses the fact that the images are a sequence in time, not an arbitrary unordered set

Comment: Absolutely - I will do that. Thanks a lot for all the help!